# Is it possible to run a dotnet cli command using C# inside a docker container

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I am trying to scaffold a new dotnet Web Api project inside a docker container using C# but getting an error `An error occurred trying to start process 'dotnet.exe' with working directory '/app'. No such file or directory`.

```cs
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "dotnet",
        Arguments = "new webapi -n WebApi"            
    }
    
};

process.Start();
```

Below is the Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base 
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Is there a way to reference the dotnet.exe inside the docker container?

Comment: Yes, as long as the .NET SDK is installed, but why? The docker file you posted creates a container *with* the .NET SDK, publishes the object and finally *only retains the published application*. The final 4 lines create a container from a .NET runtime container and only copy the published application into it. The .NET SDK isn't copied into the final container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the runtime as the base image and not the SDK. Here's the updated Dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1.csproj"
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

WORKDIR /app/publish
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```